# Using Downloaded Maps in place of Google Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, download, html, preload

The issues it this, I've built a webpage that overlays several POI on a map. I'm utilizing a Google map and the map is great when I'm in range of wifi. What I want to achieve is using a preloaded map on my laptop in place of a google map so that I don't have to worry about being off the grid. Currently the webpage is calling the map through a script tag.

`<script type="text/javascript"  src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYDEVELOPERKEY&libraries=geometry"></script>`

In an ideal situation I would like to pre-download the maps so that I can zoom in and out as if I were on wifi. Is the another solution that doesn't involve google maps?

Answer (score 0):

You can't load or save a map with the Google API, you need an internet connection at all times in order to communicate with Google and render a map.